# My progress bar can't load after back to main view and go back to download view again

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I have 2 page in storyboard by using navigation controller

I use alamofire for download file and I set progress bar in download page after I tap back to main pain and go to download view again, the progress don't load but in background it print percent normally

my custom cell code:

```
func downloadBook(bookID:String,downloadURLString:String) {
    //set up UI
    self.loadingLabel.text = "Preparing"
    UserDefaults.standard.set(kStatusPreparing, forKey: "HP\(bookID).pdf")
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    if let url = URL(string: downloadURLString) {
        self.delegate?.didTapDownloadBook(bookID: bookID, downloadURL: url)
    }
}

@IBAction func selectBook(_ sender: Any) {
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "HP\(bookID!).pdf") == kStatusSuccess {
        self.delegate?.openWebView(bookId: bookID!)
    }else if (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "HP\(bookID!).pdf") == kStatusNotDownload){
        let urlString = "http://www.narutoroyal.com/HP\(bookID!).pdf"
        downloadBook(bookID: bookID!, downloadURLString: urlString)
    }
}
```

and in my main view download code here:

```
func updateCellProgress(bookID: String,progress:Double) {
    let visibleCell = collectionBook.visibleCells as! [LoadingCollectionViewCell]
    for cell in visibleCell {
        if cell.bookID == bookID {
            print("Download Progress: \(progress*100)")
            cell.loadingLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", progress*100)
        }
    }
}

func updateCellStatus(bookID: String) {
    let visibleCell = collectionBook.visibleCells as! [LoadingCollectionViewCell]
    for cell in visibleCell {
        if cell.bookID == bookID {
            cell.loadingLabel.text = "Open"
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController : LoadingCollectionViewCellDelegate {

func didTapDownloadBook(bookID: String, downloadURL: URL) {
    Alamofire.request(downloadURL).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
        self.updateCellProgress(bookID: bookID,progress: progress.fractionCompleted)

    }).responseData { (response) in
        if let data = response.result.value {
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("HP\(bookID).pdf")
            do {
                try data.write(to:fileURL, options: .atomic)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(kStatusSuccess, forKey: "HP\(bookID).pdf")
                self.updateCellStatus(bookID: bookID)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

here my full code : https://github.com/dekphoenix/downloadprogress

ps. please help me I stuck in this many days T^T

Comment: Hi Boy, I am having exactly the same issue !! But no idea why so far. At least you have a suffering-alter-ego ;) Did you get to any solution so far ??